# only a string is returned in a mysql query in a bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

There's plenty of similar questions out there that seem to answer this, but it's not working for me.

Here's mysql query in a bash script, the resultant row comes back as a string, not as an array.
Am I missing something?

```
while read -a row;
  do
   echo "${row[0]}";
  done < <(mysql -u $dbuser -p$dbpass -N --database=$dbname --host=$dbhost --batch -se  "SELECT id, CONCAT(id, '_', filename) from photos" );
}
```

This echoes `200    200_filename.jpg`.
I would think it is supposed to echo `200`.
Echoing `${row[1]}` displays a blank line.

Comment: Have you tried `${row[0][0]}`?

Comment: Yes, same result. It's weird.

Answer (score 0):

And the magic spell is the IFS. Adding that in with the tab fixes the array issue

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -a row;
  do
   echo "${row[0]}";
  done
```